# How can I use a for-loop within a $(document).ready(function(){})?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I've been trying to modify code I found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp
to have multiple hide buttons linked with multiple paragraphs. The number of paragraphs/buttons is variable--so I'd need it to work with a for-loop or while loop.

I've gotten it to work this far:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.x'+1).click(function(){ $('.file'+1).toggle(1000);});
    $('.x'+2).click(function(){ $('.file'+2).toggle(1000);});
    $('.x'+3).click(function(){ $('.file'+3).toggle(1000);});
  });


</script>
</head>
<body>


<li class="file1">This is a paragraph with little content.</li>
<button class="x1">hide</button>
<p>
<li class="file2">This is another small paragraph.</li>
<button class="x2">hide</button>
<p>
<li class="file3">This is a paragraph.</li>
<button class="x3">hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to replace the inside of that $(document).ready(function(){}) with a for-loop it quits working. So, why doesn't this code below do anything?

```
var m,k=3;
  $(document).ready(function(){
  for (m = 1; m <=k; m++) {
    $('.x'+m).click(function(){ $('.file'+m).toggle(1000);});
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: In what way is it invalid?

Comment: List items can't be children of the body, and your paragraphs aren't closed. Run your code through a validator and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html has a problem, so assuming the button & the target elements are not siblings you can

```
<li class="file1">This is a paragraph with little content.</li>
<button class="x" data-target=".file1">hide</button>

<li class="file2">This is another small paragraph.</li>
<button class="x" data-target=".file2">hide</button>

<li class="file3">This is a paragraph.</li>
<button class="x" data-target=".file3">hide</button>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.x').click(function () {
        $($(this).data('target')).toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cv5bd88s/)

Answer (score 2):

update to this code  . [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/9qeq3Ln4/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[class^="x"').click(function(){ $(this).prev('li').toggle(1000);});
 });
```

also your html is invalid  so write proper HTML code so i can explain in more detail

Comment: It doesn't look like that does anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `.each` loop

```
$('button[class^=x]').click(function(){ 
    $(this).prev("li").toggle(1000);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9pjjkad6/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Did the demo work when you did it?

Comment: I given demo it will work. Where you stuck or where is problem in code?

Answer (score 0):

This would do in the way you planned to do it, ie using a for loop

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function addClickHandler(i) {
    $('.x'+i).click(function(){ $('.file'+i).toggle(1000);});
}

var j;
for(j = 1; j <=3; j++) {
    addClickHandler(j);
}
});
```

I would however do something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".file button").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file">
  <p>This is file 1</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
<div class="file">
  <p>This is file 2</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
<div class="file">
  <p>This is file 2</p>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

You would be using fewer class names ie file1, file2 and x1, x2 etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here are already a lot of good answers. I'd like to specifically add something crucial about JavaScript.

The problem is not the `for` loop in your `function`, but the `function` definition inside your `for` loop.

Differ between the compile time of a `function` and its execution time. In your example, compile time is during the for loop, execution time is at the moment of clicking. How can you expect your variable `m` to be the same while compile time like at execution time? If it is not the same, how can your code work?

Once your code has left the loop, anything may happen to `m`, and at the clicking time, `m` is not valid as you expect it.

This is only one example, here is more about why defining `function`s in loops may be puzzling:
http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop